# Can I declare an array in a class declaration, where the array will later be filled with elements of that class?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I usually work in C, but now I have to work with C++. I have a large file, with a lot of repetition because I can currently not traverse dir_x to dirx_z in a loop. 
1. Is there a way to make the elements in this class addressable as if it was, for instance, an array? I give an example of this in the last line. 
2. I currently refer to

```
Node * dir_x;
```

as being a link, but what is the real name so I can google it?

```
class Node {
public:
        Node(int x, int y, int z){

                //Will be initialized to point to the next Node (neighbor)
                //So will be holding elements of this same class!
                dir_x = NULL; 
                dir_y = NULL; 
                dir_z = NULL;
        }

        //These are "links", but does anybody know the name to google it?
        Node * dir_x; 
        Node * dir_x; 
        Node * dir_x; 
};

//Code snippet of a function:
//current would be the node to traverse through the collection
Node * current = someNode;
//together with next
Node * next  = NULL;
//Here the next node is actually set
next = current->dir_x;  
//But I would like a generic way like below
//to reduce code duplication by about a third:
next = current->dir[i];
```

Comment: You could make dir a Node* dir[3]. However, you shouldn't have public members dun dun duuuun.

Comment: The word is "pointer".

Comment: Why are you attempting to declare three members with the same name?  That's never going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to C++.  Many of the things that you have to build yourself in C are part of C++'s Standard Library.  It is strongly recommended to use these components rather than building your own.  In this case, you should be using a `std::list` instead of wasting all this time and brain-power on reinventing a wheel that has been perfected a million times already.

As to your question,

```
//But I would like a generic way like below
//to reduce code duplication by about a third:
next = current->dir[i];
```

You can implement an `operator[](size_t)` on your `Node` class.  I'm guessing it would be something along these lines:

```
class Node
{
public:
  Node * mLeft; 
  Node * mRight; 

  Node& operator[] (size_t i) 
  {
    if (!i)
      return *this;
    return (*mRight)[i-1];
  }
};
```

Of course this is just an exposition.  You have much work to do on your own to handle things like range checking, exception safety, and the like.

Comment: I would definately look at using a container rather than manually implementing an C style linked list

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a linked list

```
    // this would not compile
    Node * dir_x; 
    Node * dir_x; 
    Node * dir_x; 

    // i think you meant
    Node * dir_x; 
    Node * dir_y; 
    Node * dir_z;
```

What you can do is

```
    Node* dir[3]; // now this contains 3 pointers to node elements
```

and you can use it as you want

```
    Node* node_x = node->dir[0];
    Node* node_y = node->dir[1];
    Node* node_z = node->dir[2];
```

Unless `node->dir[2]` is supposed to give you the second node. Which would also be possible to implement.